# How to extract and visualize feature value for an arbitrary layer during inference with YOLOv7?

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection, yolo, yolov7

In my case, I would like to extract and visualize the features output in layers 102, 103, 104 in the following code in `cfg/training/yolov7.yaml`.

```
# yolov7 head
head:
  [[-1, 1, SPPCSPC, [512]], # 51
  
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],
   [37, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]], # route backbone P4
   [[-1, -2], 1, Concat, [1]],
   
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]], # 63
   
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, nn.Upsample, [None, 2, 'nearest']],
   [24, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]], # route backbone P3
   [[-1, -2], 1, Concat, [1]],
   
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [64, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]], # 75
      
   [-1, 1, MP, []],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-3, 1, Conv, [128, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, -3, 63], 1, Concat, [1]],
   
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [128, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]], # 88
      
   [-1, 1, MP, []],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-3, 1, Conv, [256, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 2]],
   [[-1, -3, 51], 1, Concat, [1]],
   
   [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 1, 1]],
   [-2, 1, Conv, [512, 1, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [256, 3, 1]],
   [[-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6], 1, Concat, [1]],
   [-1, 1, Conv, [512, 1, 1]], # 101
   
   [75, 1, RepConv, [256, 3, 1]],   #extract
   [88, 1, RepConv, [512, 3, 1]],   #extract
   [101, 1, RepConv, [1024, 3, 1]], #extract

   [[102,103,104], 1, IDetect, [nc, anchors]],   # Detect(P3, P4, P5)
  ]
```

Also, the following is the result of printing out the model.

```
Model(
  (model): Sequential(
    (0): Conv(
      (conv): Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (act): SiLU(inplace=True)
    )
    (1): Conv(
      (conv): Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1))
      (act): SiLU(inplace=True)
    )
    (2): Conv(
      (conv): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
      (act): SiLU(inplace=True)
    )
----------------------------------------------------
    (102): RepConv(
      (act): SiLU(inplace=True)
      (rbr_reparam): Conv2d(128, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)) # extract
    )
    (103): RepConv(
      (act): SiLU(inplace=True)
      (rbr_reparam): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)) # extract
    )
    (104): RepConv(
      (act): SiLU(inplace=True)
      (rbr_reparam): Conv2d(512, 1024, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1)) # extract
    )
    (105): IDetect(
      (m): ModuleList(
        (0): Conv2d(256, 21, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        (1): Conv2d(512, 21, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        (2): Conv2d(1024, 21, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
      )
      (ia): ModuleList(
        (0): ImplicitA()
        (1): ImplicitA()
        (2): ImplicitA()
      )
      (im): ModuleList(
        (0): ImplicitM()
        (1): ImplicitM()
        (2): ImplicitM()
      )
    )
  )
)
```

However, I would like to be able to take out features of any layer if possible, as I may need features of layers other than this one.

How can I do this?

I tried to do the extraction and visualization from the `Model` class in `models/yolo.py` with reference to https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/3089, but could not figure out which code to edit and how.
I tried to do the same with the `IDetect` class, but could not figure it out either.

Comment: Suggest this tutorial:   https://kozodoi.me/python/deep%20learning/pytorch/tutorial/2021/05/27/extracting-features.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DerekG for helping me figure this out!
The following is the code in `yolov7/detect.py` after the resolution.
The `-----` line indicates the omission of a code.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
from utils.plots import plot_one_box, plot_ts_feature_maps # Add plot_ts_feature_maps method
-------------------------------------------------------------
def detect(save_img=False):
-------------------------------------------------------------
    # Load model
    model = attempt_load(weights, map_location=device)  # load FP32 model
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Set Dataloader
    vid_path, vid_writer = None, None
    if webcam:
        view_img = check_imshow()
        cudnn.benchmark = True  # set True to speed up constant image size inference
        dataset = LoadStreams(source, img_size=imgsz, stride=stride)
    else:
        dataset = LoadImages(source, img_size=imgsz, stride=stride)
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    for path, img, im0s, vid_cap in dataset:
        img = torch.from_numpy(img).to(device)
        img = img.half() if half else img.float()  # uint8 to fp16/32
        img /= 255.0  # 0 - 255 to 0.0 - 1.0
        if img.ndimension() == 3:
            img = img.unsqueeze(0)
        ------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Start of postscript

        def make_hook(key):
            def hook(model, input, output):
                intermediate_output[key] = output.detach()
            return hook

        layer_num = 104　# Intermediate layer number
        intermediate_output = {}
        model.model[layer_num].register_forward_hook(make_hook(layer_num))

        # forward pass
        model(img)

        # print feature map shape
        feature_maps = intermediate_output[layer_num]
        print(feature_maps.shape)

        # Outputs a feature map of the intermediate layer
        plot_ts_feature_maps(feature_maps)

        # End of postscript

        t2 = time_synchronized()
        ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also, `yolov7/utils/plots.py` was added as follows.
Torchshow is a module to visualize Tensor. Here is the official GitHub: https://github.com/xwying/torchshow

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add module
import torchshow as ts
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add plot_ts_feature_maps method at the bottom
def plot_ts_feature_maps(feature_maps):
    import matplotlib
    matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
    feature_maps = feature_maps.to(torch.float32)
    ts.show(feature_maps[0])
```

As a test, to extract 4 feature maps for the second layer, I changed `layer_num = 1` in `detect.py` and `ts.show(feature_maps[0][:4])` in `plots.py` and ran the following command.

```
python detect.py --weights yolov7.pt --source inference/images/horses.jpg --device 0 --no-trace
```

The inference results and feature maps were then output as follows.
[inference results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpXTx.jpg)
[feature map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdKrz.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can register a forward hook to the layer(s) in question. Per [pytorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.modules.module.register_module_forward_hook.html), "The hook will be called every time after forward() has computed an output."

Essentially, the forward hook function modifies a variable of global scope that will persist after the layer `forward` call terminates. You store the output of the layer `forward` call (by way of the forward hook function) in this variable, and you can then reference it later.

(Explicitly, I believe what happens is that registering the forward hook implicitly changes the `nn.module` in  question to be of global scope such that the value persists after the termination of the function call. See pytorch docs for more on this.)

In any case , the forward hook function needs the following function signature:

```
hook(module, input, output) -> None or modified output
```

So, a trivial example would be:

```
def make_hook(key):
    def hook(model, input, output):
        intermediate_output[key] = output.detach()
    return hook
```

The outer function itself returns a function, as the input to `register_module_forward_hook` is a function with the above signature.

Then we can add the forward hook to any module with:

```
model.<layer_name>.register_forward_hook(make_hook("example_key"))
```

So, in summary, your code would look something like:

```
def make_hook(key):
    def hook(model, input, output):
        intermediate_output[key] = output.detach()
    return hook

# define model
model = Yolo5() # I know this is wrong but you didn't include the actual model in your question so this is just an example
intermediate_output = {}


# register hook to as many layers as you want
model.conv4.register_forward_hook("conv4") # same here, I made these layer names up
model.maxpool8.register_forward_hook("maxpool8")


# dummy input
inp = torch.random.rand(1,3,1080,1920)

# forward pass
model(inp)

# reference intermediate_output
intermediate_output["conv4"] # should have the output from this layer stored as value
```

Do note that because using forward hooks "adds global state" to the `module` pytorch docs suggest to use this feature only temporarily for debugging purposes and not for persistent solutions. For a longer-term solution you could modify the `forward` pass of the main model architecture to store these values as intermediate outputs and return all of these values at the end.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in replying. And thank you for your response.
I tried to put in the code you provided, but it returned two errors: "intermediate_output is not defined" and "intermediate_outputs is not defined".
Where and how should I define intermediate_output and intermediate_outputs?

Also, I added the result of printout of model to my question. For example, if I want to extract the conv layers 0, 102, 103, and 104 of this model, how should I define <layer_name> in "model.<layer_name>.register_forward_hook"?

Comment: Edited to answer the first question. The layers have names by default, this is the name of the pytorch module. If you `print(model)`, the layer names will be listed in parentheses

Comment: For instance, (105) indicates the module name is 105.