# How to obtain feature map generated from first convolution layer of YOLOv5?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, feature-extraction, yolov5

I would like to obtain feature map generated from first convolution layer of YOLOv5 (PyTorch). How can I get the feature map?

Comment: Already answered here I believe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75319661/how-to-extract-and-visualize-feature-value-for-an-arbitrary-layer-during-inferen/75324597#75324597

Comment: How can I do it using forward pass of main model architecture. Can you please explain ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract and visualize feature value for an arbitrary layer during inference with YOLOv7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75319661/how-to-extract-and-visualize-feature-value-for-an-arbitrary-layer-during-inferen)

Comment: As you mentioned in the post for a longer-term solution you could modify the forward pass of the main model architecture to store these values as intermediate outputs and return all of these values at the end. I am trying to achieve using forward pass. Can you help ?

Comment: The `register_hook` solution works every time you complete a forward pass. You can modify your forward call to return both the final and an intermediate output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is trivial to modify the network structure to save an intermediate output. Here I save the output from the first conv and pooling layer as `x1`, and return this value as well in the `forward` call. Now if you try to use this approach in an off-the-shelf manner (i.e. if you didn't write your own training script and loss function) this will likely cause an error during training as the loss function call probably does not expect an additional output from `forward`. Thus, the preferred solution for drop-in modifications to existing nn libraries is to use the `register_hook` approach linked in the comments.

Here's a trivial example network from [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html).

```
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
    self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
    self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

  def forward(self, x):
    x1 = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
    x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x1)))
    x = torch.flatten(x, 1) # flatten all dimensions except batch
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
    x = self.fc3(x)
    return x,x1


net = Net()
```