# Is there a way to monitor how the shapes are changing inside VGG19 pretrained model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, vgg-net

So the thing is I am trying to do something with VGG19 pretrained model and initial 8 convolution layers are frozen.
My image size is `3 x 400 x 400` and I do not want to resize as it may affect the performance. I am getting error again and again that the matrices can not be multiplied, so is there a way to pass `3 x 400 x 400` image through vgg19?

```
weights = VGG19_Weights.DEFAULT
vgg19_layer = vgg19(weights = weights)

for i in range(16):
    for param in vgg19_layer.features[i].parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False
```

This is how I am using `vgg19_layer`.

```
self.vgg19 = vgg19_layer
```

This is how I am currently sending the input.

```
x = torch.randn((3, 400, 400))

model(x)
```

### Output

```
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (512x49 and 25088x4096)
```

Comment: Yes, two common approaches are i.) for debugging purposes, simply add print statements to print the shape of the result after each layer in the forward function ii.) register hooks (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75319661/how-to-extract-and-visualize-feature-value-for-an-arbitrary-layer-during-inferen/75324597#75324597)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the shape of your input tensor is incorrect. The model expects a shape [B, 3, 400, 400] with B being the batch size. If you send a single image at a time to your model, then you need to use a tensor of shape [1, 3, 400, 400] and not [3, 400, 400]. You can achieve this with `torch.unsqueeze()`. At the output of the network, you can eliminate this dimension with `torch.squeeze()`.

Also note that instead of explicitly setting `require_grad` to `false`, you can simply put the model in evaluation mode (`model.eval()`) and also decorate your inference function with `torch.no_grad()`. This will immediately deactivate any gradient calculations within the function.

To further clarify, the model expects a tensor of shape [B, 3, 400, 400] where B represents the batch size, 3 represents the RGB color channels, and 400x400 is the image resolution. If you are sending a single image, it needs to be reshaped to [1, 3, 400, 400] for the model to process it correctly. The `torch.unsqueeze()` function can be used to add an additional dimension required for batch processing. Similarly, `torch.squeeze()` can be used to remove this extra dimension after the image has been processed.

Finally, when performing inference, it's not necessary to compute gradients. You can stop PyTorch from calculating gradients by using `torch.no_grad()`. This can save memory and speed up your code. Also, remember to set your model to evaluation mode using `model.eval()` before running inference. This will set all the layers in your model to evaluation mode, which is essential for some types of layers like dropout and batch normalization which behave differently during training and evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get summary about layers of your model use torchsummary, an example below

```
from torchsummary import summary
summary(CNNNetwork().cuda(), (1, 64, 16))



----------------------------------------------------------------
        Layer (type)               Output Shape         Param #
================================================================
            Conv2d-1           [-1, 16, 64, 16]             416
       BatchNorm2d-2           [-1, 16, 64, 16]              32
              ReLU-3           [-1, 16, 64, 16]               0
         MaxPool2d-4            [-1, 16, 32, 8]               0
            Conv2d-5            [-1, 32, 32, 8]          12,832
              ReLU-6            [-1, 32, 32, 8]               0
         MaxPool2d-7            [-1, 32, 16, 4]               0
       BatchNorm2d-8            [-1, 32, 16, 4]              64
            Conv2d-9            [-1, 64, 18, 6]          18,496
             ReLU-10            [-1, 64, 18, 6]               0
        MaxPool2d-11             [-1, 64, 9, 3]               0
      BatchNorm2d-12             [-1, 64, 9, 3]             128
           Conv2d-13           [-1, 128, 11, 5]          73,856
             ReLU-14           [-1, 128, 11, 5]               0
        MaxPool2d-15            [-1, 128, 5, 2]               0
      BatchNorm2d-16            [-1, 128, 5, 2]             256
          Flatten-17                 [-1, 1280]               0
           Linear-18                   [-1, 35]          44,835
================================================================
Total params: 150,915
Trainable params: 150,915
Non-trainable params: 0
----------------------------------------------------------------
Input size (MB): 0.00
Forward/backward pass size (MB): 0.83
Params size (MB): 0.58
Estimated Total Size (MB): 1.41
----------------------------------------------------------------
```